# Unable to convert .jar file to .dex

Tags: java, compilation, dex

I have decompiled the classes.dex file and edited the .java files I wanted to. However, I am having trouble recompiling it back into a .dex file.

I've been trying to convert the .jar file into .dex with the windows powershell in

C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools. with SDK I use the command

```
dx --dex --output="c:\temp\dx.dex" "c:\temp\in.jar"
```

and am greeted with the message,

"the term 'dx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Check the Android sdk folder for `dx.bat` this is the script to start with. Note that `dx` is deprecated and was replaced by `d8`. d8 has the advantage that it supports Java 8 features.